# Chainlink Functions: _Error thrown in sandboxed source code__ Cannot find module './server.js'

Tags: node.js, node-modules, chainlink

Building on the Functions-ChatGPT integration workshop, I wrote `server.js` code in which the idea is to get a ChatGPT prompt from the user from another client. The steps my server takes are:

1. listens for a client request on a `/chatgpt` endpoint,
2. strips the body message (prompt) from the request, and
3. loads the message to a global object and exports it via module export to another source file (call it `Functions-request-source.js` like in the workshop).
4. Executes a child process to run `npx hardhat functions-simulate` under assumption that the exported prompt is being used as an input parameter to the `Functions-request-source.js` which will be called by the `npx hardhat functions-simulate` command. My `Functions-request-source.js` is the file I've used in my `Functions-request-config` file.

I think this should be a straight forward enough process (especially exporting my prompt as a global object) but when I run the program, I receive the message `__Error thrown in sandboxed source code__ Cannot find module ./server.js`. I believe my issue is that `Functions-request-source.js` doesn't seem to be reading my module.export from `server.js`, but I'm not sure why. I provided my code for `server.js` and `Functions-request-source.js` below.

`server.js`

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const { exec } = require("child_process")
const port = 3667

app.use(bodyParser.json())

let telegramInputObj = {
  telegramInput: null,
  setTelegramInput: function (input) {
    this.telegramInput = input
  },
  getTelegramInput: function () {
    return this.telegramInput
  },
}

app.post("/chatgpt", (req, res) => {
  const message = req.body.message
  console.log(`received message from client: ${message}`)

  //Set global object variable
  telegramInputObj.setTelegramInput(message)
  console.log("global telegram input: " + telegramInputObj.getTelegramInput())

  //Command for child process
  const command = "npx hardhat functions-simulate"

  //Execute child process
  exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`)
      res.status(500).send(`Error: ${error}`)
      return
    }

    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    res.send(stdout)
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

module.exports = telegramInputObj
```

`Functions-request-source.js`

```
const telegramInputObj = require("./server.js")

console.log("Imported telegram input is: " + telegramInputObj.getTelegramInput())

const prompt = telegramInputObj.getTelegramInput()

if (!secrets.openaiKey) {
  throw Error("Need to set OPENAI_KEY environment variable")
}

// example request:
// curl https://api.openai.com/v1/completions -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" -d '{"model": "text-davinci-003", "prompt": "Say this is a test", "temperature": 0, "max_tokens": 7}

// example response:
// {"id":"cmpl-6jFdLbY08kJobPRfCZL4SVzQ6eidJ","object":"text_completion","created":1676242875,"model":"text-davinci-003","choices":[{"text":"\n\nThis is indeed a test","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":"length"}],"usage":{"prompt_tokens":5,"completion_tokens":7,"total_tokens":12}}
const openAIRequest = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${secrets.openaiKey}`,
  },
  data: { model: "text-davinci-003", prompt: prompt, temperature: 1, max_tokens: 7 },
})

const [openAiResponse] = await Promise.all([openAIRequest])
console.log("raw response", openAiResponse)

const result = openAiResponse.data.choices[0].text

return Functions.encodeString(result)
```

I have tried pointing my user prompt from `server.js` directly to the `Functions-request-config.js` file using the `args` parameter of the `requestConfig` object. I've also tried exporting the prompt as a variable instead of an object. Both didn't help. I've double checked that my require() statements at the top of my `Functions-request-source.js` file are also using the correct file path (they're in the same directory).

Hoping someone might be able to help out, as I'm pretty junior to the dev space. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

junior and senior people struggle with learning new things, so i wouldnt worry about that :)

Ok so whats happening is that you're trying to import code into your custom source.js file

"const telegramInputObj = require("./server.js")" <---- this

Thats not allowed for security reasons -- the Functions-request-source.js file cannot contain imports other than specific node js libraries that are allowlisted by Functions.  This is essential to maintain code security so that arbitrary and malicious code doesnt get imported.

See more here:

https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit#javascript-code

since you're trying to access "telegramInputObj" inside your custom code, why dont you just send that in request config as an "args" item?  parse the JSON into a String (JSON.stringify()) and then send the arg as one long string, and then inside your custom JS do JSON.parse(telegramInputObj) to get it converted back into a JS object?

Try that and see if it works!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I did try that; now I'm getting a different error: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3667`. I think that I shouldn't be executing the `npx hardhat functions-simulate` as a child process as running server & child are competing for the same port nums? Thinking on your suggestion, is it advisable to rewrite the request config file to act as a server listener for client requests? Or is `functions-simulate` call intended to be executed by a server intermediary apart custom source code if we're waiting for input? Wondering where to stick express server.

Comment: Not sure why your request config file should be a server listener? the config file is simply where the data is stored for the tool to ingest to send to your FunctionsConsumer.sol client contract

There is something in your architecture which is confusing the concepts here

Comment: Also, when running functions-simulate your functions JS code is run in a simulated VM environment on your machine.  If its fetching data from an API that is served on your local machine then it will be trying to fetch data form localhost (http://localhost:<<port number>>

but it is possible that the VM is being port blocked or the loopback interface to localhost is blocked or they're just misconfigured.  we would need more data to understand whats going on here.